# Kendo grid, ToDataSouceResult with EF4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a KendoGrid, i set the datasource with the event read:

```
public virtual JsonResult ContactsListRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   return Json(ContactsModel.ContactsService.Get().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

the method ContactsModel.ContactsService.Get(), return me an IQueryable:

```
 var qContactsOpen = from x in promo.Contacts
                                            where x.type == type && (x.closure_id == 0 || x.closure_id == null)
                                            orderby x.id descending
                                            select new ContactsGrid
                                            {
                                                Id = x.id,
                                                DescriptionA = x.description_A,
                                                Address = x.address,
                                                PhoneA = x.phone_A,
                                                CategoryDescription = x.Categories.description,
                                                Location = x.location,
                                                Subject = x.subject,
                                                Note = x.ContactsActivities.Where(o=>o.promotion_id == promo.id).OrderByDescending(o => o.date).Select(o => o.note).FirstOrDefault() ?? "",
                                            };

                        return (qContactsOpen.AsQueryable());
```

on the grid i have Paging(20), so, I expect that whatever is the number of records in the query, the ContactsListRead, take a little time, instead for large amount of record it take much time...

i've forgot something?

Comment: I'd advise you incorporate paging a lot earlier into the equation. Only select what you need.

Comment: I thought that with the ToDataSourceResult(), i don't need any 'Take()' in my query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved adding customs filters/sort/paging in read event, and setting ServerOperation(true) in grid.. and it work perfectly

```
    public ActionResult ContactsListRead([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IEnumerable<ContactsModel.ContactsGrid> query = ContactsModel.ContactsService.Get();

        int count = ContactsModel.ContactsService.GetCount();

        query = AjaxCustomBindingExtensions.ApplyOrdersFiltering(query, request.Filters, out count, count);

        query = AjaxCustomBindingExtensions.ApplyOrdersSorting(query, request.Groups, request.Sorts);

        query = AjaxCustomBindingExtensions.ApplyOrdersPaging(query, request.Page, request.PageSize);

        IEnumerable data = AjaxCustomBindingExtensions.ApplyOrdersGrouping(query, request.Groups);

        var result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            Data = data,
            Total = count
        };

        return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set `serverPaging` to `true` in your DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the DataSourceRequest is empty. Make sure you have included kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js in your page.